# Ordered Chain Rule of Probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

For the chain rule of probability the order of variables does not matter and sets are not ordered as of themselves anyway. So therefore $P(A | B) P(B) = P(A \cap B) = P(B|A) P(A)$.

However, I cannot reconcile this with a scenario like in the following tree of (conditional) probabilities.

`-|
  -- (.1) -- A -|
  |             -- (.7) -- A
  |             |
  |             -- (.3) -- B
  |
  -- (.9) -- B -|
                -- (.4) -- A
                |
                -- (.6) -- B`

This actually does not satisfy the symmetry from above, as the order does matter:

$P((B,A)) = P(B) P(A|B) = .9 \times .4$

and

$P((A,B)) = P(A) P(B|A) = .1 \times .3$

When I search for "ordered joint distribution" or "ordered chain rule of probability" I don't find anything useful.

So, my suspicion is that I am fundamentally confused about something here. If that is the case, can you point out my misconception?

Alternatively I am just using the wrong search terms...

Comment: That tree does not make any sort of sense.  According to it, $\mathsf P(A,A)=0.1\cdot 0.7$. ...

Comment: Hmm... Why is that a problem?

Comment: Ah, I see why that is a problem and why I first did not see why. I thought of tuples of events rather than intersections of events. But sometimes events are tuples, like n-gram probablilities: $\frac{\text{count}((w_1, w_2))}{\text{count}(w_1)} = P(w_2 | w_1)$, where the $w_i$ are any words. And here the order does indeed matter, hence tuples. So... I am still confused.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional proability $\mathsf P(A\mid B)$ is *defined* as $\mathsf P(A\cap B)\div\mathsf P(B)$, when $\mathsf P(B)\neq 0$.

Likewise $\mathsf P(B\mid A):=\mathsf P(A\cap B)\div\mathsf P(A)$ .   (Since $A\cap B = B\cap A)$ .

So it is definitely the case that $\mathsf P(A)~\mathsf P(B\mid A)~{=\mathsf P(A\cap B)\\=\mathsf P(B)~\mathsf P(A\mid B)}$

---

> However, I cannot reconcile this with a scenario like in the following tree of (conditional) probabilities.

The tree just does not make any sense.   Check the labels.